# Cannot run specs with jRuby 9.1.17 in Rubymine 2019.1

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I have installed the new version of RubyMine (Rubymine 2019.1) but i cannot run specs anymore. I assume i am missing a setting...

- Settings > Languages and Frameworks: 'Ruby SDK: jRuby 9.1.17.0p0' selected
- Tools > Bundler > Install/update (My gem file states that rspec 3.5 is installed)
- Rubymine restart

When I right click a test and click the 'run test' action(same run configuration in previous version):

> Error running 'my test' Lib filer wasn't found 'test-unit' gem of Ruby
>   SDK with interpeter 'C:/jruby-9.1.17.0/bin/jruby.exe'

If i try it with jRuby 9.2.0 it seems to run but my project gems don't work with jRuby 9.1.17. Is it possible to still execute specs with jruby 9.1.17?

Comment: just to be sure, do you manage to run these tests manually from the command line?

Comment: Command line works and the old Rubymine still works also...

Answer (score 0):

It may be the issue with surplus apostrophes in the file name mask - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-25035

Check Run/Debug Configurations and remove them, if present.

[image]